# Struggle with a Regex to change subdomain, and subsubdomain

Tags: javascript, regex, dns

I got this from antoher post:

```
host = ".mylocal.com";
var reg = new RegExp('^https?://([^.]*' + host + ')');
console.log(reg.test('http://www.mylocal.com/'));
```

but it can only match with  www.mylocal.com , whatever.mylocal.com   but not two levels down, like dev.www.mylocal.com

i tried writing something else but couldn't get it check the sub -sub . or even 3, 4 levels down. :(  how should i write it?

so, what I would like to achieve is:

```
.local.com
will match:
www.local.com
dev.www.local.com
abc.dev.abc.local.com

and 
www.local.com
will only match 
www.local.com
NOT dev.www.local.com
```

:)  that's more clear

Comment: Am I mistaken, or will ".mylocal.com" in the expression match any one character, "mylocal", any other character, and "com"? A quick test suggests it matches "www.mylocal.com" as well as "www/mylocal.com" and "wwwamylocalbcom".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that you want to match all kinds of prefixes, followed by `host`, if `host` begins with `.`; but you want to match `host` alone if not.  This could be done with lookahead assertions, but since you're constructing the regex anyway, it's much simpler to just construct it differently depending on the case. I don't know Javascript, so I'll use pseudocode.

For the first case, we want to match zero or more (non-capturing) groups of non-periods followed by one period, then at least one non-period, all before `host`. For the second case, we just want to match `host`.

```
if host starts with '.':
    var reg = new RegExp('^https?://((?:[^.]+\.)*[^.]+' + host + ')');
else:
    var reg = new RegExp('^https?://(' + host + ')');
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you're trying to do. this regex will match any number of levels:

```
r = new RegExp("^https?://([^.]+[.])*([^.])+$");
```